# SQL Select for a book format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently came across a Postgres SQL select test problem which I hadn't seen and had trouble coming up with the correct answer.  A table basically contains page numbers and page titles for a book, and the object is to create a SELECT that will lay out the book as follows:

> left_page, right_page

where left_page contains all even page #'s and right_page contains all odd page numbers, but where the 0 page shows null and where any non-consecutive page would have a null.  There can be blank pages, so page numbers can skip.

My guess was to use the Lag or Lead functions to find the next page in order, then see if it was consecutive, but ran into problems.

Here's an example:

```sql
create table mysharkbook (page_no integer not null, title varchar(30) not null, unique(page_no));
insert into mysharkbook (page_no,title) VALUES (1,'Hammerhead');
insert into mysharkbook (page_no,title) VALUES (2,'Great White');
insert into mysharkbook (page_no,title) VALUES (3,'Blue');
insert into mysharkbook (page_no,title) VALUES (4,'Tiger');
insert into mysharkbook (page_no,title) VALUES (6,'Blacktip');
select * from mysharkbook;
```

Results

```
1   "Hammerhead"
2   "Great White"
3   "Blue"
4   "Tiger"
6   "Blacktip"
```

Now, try to get the SELECT to list like this:

```
left_page, right_page
null        | Hammerhead
Great White | Blue
Tiger       | null
Blacktip    | null
```

Here was my (poor) attempt at it:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN prev_page IS NULL OR prev_page <> page_no - 1 OR (page_no % 2) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE title END As left_title,
CASE WHEN (page_no % 2) = 1 THEN title ELSE NULL END As right_title
FROM
(
SELECT LAG (page_no, 1) OVER (
 ORDER BY
 page_no
 ) AS prev_page,
title,page_no
from mysharkbook
order by page_no
) d
```

Any ideas on the best way?

Comment: Why was this question flagged as "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: Not sure why it was flagged as such.  But all the four answerers (word?) so far are studs!  Great choices for how to do this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another:

```
select distinct on (page.no / 2)
    msb.title, lead(msb.title) over(order by page.no)
from generate_series(0, (select max(page_no) from  mysharkbook)) page(no) 
left join mysharkbook msb on page.no = msb.page_no
order by page.no / 2
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Accepted.  Simplest and most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, put the page titles into two-elements array

```
select 
    page_titles[1] as left_page, page_titles[2] as right_page
from
(
    select 
        page.no / 2 as even_pages, array_agg(title order by page.no) as page_titles
    from generate_series(0, (select max(page_no) from  mysharkbook)) page(no) 
    left join mysharkbook msb on page.no = msb.page_no
    group by even_pages
) t
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A full join of subqueries getting the odd and even pages might work. For the odd pages we additionally left join to a `generate_series()` to get pages, that might be missing.

```
SELECT even.title left_page,
       odd.title right_page
       FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM mysharkbook b
                    WHERE b.page_no % 2 = 0) even
            FULL JOIN (SELECT gs.pn page_no,
                              b.title
                              FROM generate_series(1,
                                                   (SELECT max(b.page_no)
                                                           FROM mysharkbook b),
                                                   2) gs (pn)
                                   LEFT JOIN mysharkbook b
                                             ON b.page_no = gs.pn) odd
                      ON odd.page_no = even.page_no + 1
       ORDER BY odd.page_no;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=2b6a139f807bb2fd586c8160aa34cf1c)

(P.S.: I like the idea with the sharks as sample! Not the fruits used again and again.)

Comment: Why not use `generate_series` as the “base” query, then join the actual data (twice) to that?

Comment: @Zack: Yes, that's also a possibility. Maybe that's cleaner. You should write an answer suggesting your approach I think.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for;

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT generate_series(0, (
                SELECT max(page_no) max_pages
                FROM mysharkbook
                )) AS page
    )
SELECT cte.page
    ,l.title l_title
    ,r.title r_title
FROM cte
LEFT OUTER JOIN mysharkbook l ON l.page_no = cte.page
LEFT OUTER JOIN mysharkbook r ON r.page_no = cte.page + 1
WHERE mod(page, 2) = 0
ORDER BY page
```

There might be a better way though.

-HTH

Answer (score 1):

Another approach of single pass of join and group by.

It doesn't matter if it is using min / max. The technique is to fetch the even and odd pages using modulo 2. If I'm not mistaken this simulates Oracle's MIN + KEEP DENSE_RANK combo.

```
select 
    min(title) filter(where page.no % 2 = 0) as left_page,
    min(title) filter(where page.no % 2 = 1) as right_page,
    max(title) filter(where page.no % 2 = 0) as left_page_x,
    max(title) filter(where page.no % 2 = 1) as right_page_x                           
from generate_series(0, (select max(page_no) from  mysharkbook)) page(no) 
left join mysharkbook msb on page.no = msb.page_no
group by page.no / 2
order by page.no / 2
```

To illustrate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the page numbers can skip, generating a series from 0 to max(page_no) will produce results which are completely blank (left side is null, right side is null).

What about splitting the record sets in even and odd pile, joining the 2 sets together in sequential order -> left page + 1 = right page.

```
-- Test accepted solution by an additional row
insert into mysharkbook (page_no,title) VALUES (10,'Baby shark');

SELECT ls.title, rs.title
FROM
(SELECT * FROM  mysharkbook WHERE mod(page_no,2) = 0) as ls
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM  mysharkbook WHERE mod(page_no,2) <> 0) as rs
ON ls.page_no + 1 = rs.page_no
ORDER BY COALESCE(ls.page_no, rs.page_no);
```

This however does require 2 passes over same table - not so performant perhaps.